# One NSOperationQueue per cell or per UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a UITableView where I download data from a remote server one by one when the cells appear.

Is it safe to create one NSOperationQueue per cell? I am worried that this may trigger thread explosion (if there are too many threads).
Having NSOperationQueue per cell instance is easier for development, because once the cell gets reused, I can just cancel all operations on the NSOperationQueue.

In contrast, if I use one NSOperationQueue per UIViewController, then I can pass the NSOperationQueue to the cell, and the cell can add its NSOperation to that queue. But, I need to handle in some way such that I can cancel that operation when the cell gets reused (store reference to the NSOperation in a dictionary inside the UIViewController, etc.).

Most tutorials have one NSOperationQueue in the UIViewController, but I have seen one where he used one NSOperationQueue for each cell.

Comment: the best example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html by Apple just follow it .

Comment: hey @MikeAlter do you have other reasons, not just because the Apple sample code uses this approach, or other tutorials also use that approach? thanks

Comment: i have implemented that example ,the way of ws calling and image downloading is awesome and also performance friendly

Answer (score 0):

In given below tutorial provide the option for the cancel operation and also resume operation according to your requirement.

**A good example from Ray Wenderlich** : http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788

**Update:**

If you have use `NSOperationQueue`  in `UITableView` then You need to manage properly. For example AFNetworking library have use `NSOperationQueue` for image downloading from url and other task that's work fine. So my suggestion is if you want use `NSOperationQueue` in `UITableView` then manage it properly otherwise it definitely cause an issue in future to handle long data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not asking way to do that. I want to know which way is better, and if there are dangers on using NSOperationQueue for each cell.

Comment: I hope you realise that a cell can and will display many, many different rows in a table view, so one NSOperationQueue per cell probably doesn't achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: @gnasher729 This can be achieved. If you look at the question description, I described there that I cancel all operations of the NSOperationQueue of a cell if the cell is being reused. So even if it displays Row 1 for example at the start, and an NSOperation for Row 1 is ongoing, if it goes offscreen and then gets reused for Row 10, the NSOperation for Row 1 gets cancelled, and I add new NSOperation for Row 10.